# Java unable to decode € with UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, decode

In my application I load all Lines from a file with the content:

`EUR=€`

with this command

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(currenciesPath) .toAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

but although the charset is set to utf-8 i receive the following error

`java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`

what do I have to do to decode the € symbol and other currency symbols like $,₤

Comment: Are you sure your file is encoded in UTF-8 and not some code page?

Comment: To add to @litelite how do you know it is utf-8?

Comment: @litelite how do I find out?

Comment: @aesthetic Open it in a nice text editor like Notepad++ or sublime. It's not 100% accurate(and no way will ever be), but they do a good job at guessing.

Comment: Or open it in a binary file editor ("hex editor") and find the bytes used to represent the symbols in question - include those bytes (as hex) in the question.

Comment: Use a DataInputStream to read the bytes of a file containing `EUR=€` and display their values.